# Logging pattern in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing some code to do logging in Haskell.
In imperative languages I would (have) written something like:

```
log = new Logger();
log.registerEndpoint(new ConsoleEndpoint(settings));
log.registerEndpoint(new FileEndpoint(...));
log.registerEndpoint(new ScribeEndpoint(...));
...
log.warn("beware!")
log.info("hello world");
```

Maybe even make `log` a global static so I don't have to pass it around. The actual endpoints and setting would be configured at startup from a config file maybe, eg. one for production, one for development.

What's a good pattern to do something like this in Haskell?

Comment: Use the [hslogger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger) package.

Comment: Global statics definitely won't really happen. Try looking at [configurator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/configurator) for using config files, the Writer monad for logging from pure code, and [hslogger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger-1.2.1) for structuring and formatting the logs themselves.

Answer (score 6):

The `pipes` package lets you separate data generation from data consumption.  You write your program as a producer of log `String`s, and then you choose at runtime how to consume those `String`s.

For example, let's say you have the following simple program:

```
import Control.Proxy

program :: (Proxy p) => () -> Producer p String IO r
program () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    lift $ putStrLn "Enter a string:"
    str <- lift getLine
    respond $ "User entered: " ++ str
```

The type says that it is a `Producer` of `String`s (in this case, log strings), that can also invoke `IO` commands using `lift`.  So for ordinary `IO` commands that don't involve logging you just use `lift`.  Whenever you need to log something you use the `respond` command, which produces a `String`.

This creates an abstract producer of strings that doesn't specify how they are consumed.  This lets us defer the choice of how to use the produced `String`s later.  Whenever we call the `respond` command, we abstractly hand off our log string to some as-yet-unspecified downstream stage that will handle it for us.

Now let's write a program that takes a `Bool` flag from the command line that specifies whether or not to write the output to `stdout` or to the file `"my.log"`.

```
import System.IO
import Options.Applicative

options :: Parser Bool
options = switch (long "file")

main = do
    useFile <- execParser $ info (helper <*> options) fullDesc
    if useFile
        then do
            withFile "my.log" WriteMode $ \h ->
                runProxy $ program >-> hPutStrLnD h
        else runProxy $ program >-> putStrLnD
```

If the user does not supply any flag on the command line, `useFile` defaults to `False`, indicating that we want to log to `stdout`.  If the user supplies the `--file` flag, `useFile` defaults to `True`, indicating that we want to log to `"my.log"`.

Now, check out the two `if` branches.  The first branch feeds the `String`s that `program` produces into the file using the `(>->)` operator.  Think of `hPutStrLnD` as something that takes a `Handle` and creates an abstract consumer of `String`s that writes each string to that handle.  when we connect `program` to `hPutStrLnD`, we send every log string to the file:

```
$ ./log
Enter a string:
Test<Enter>
User entered: Test
Enter a string:
Apple<Enter>
User entered: Apple
^C
$
```

The second `if` branch feeds the `String`s to `putStrLnD`, which just writes them to `stdout`:

```
$ ./log --file
Enter a string:
Test<Enter>
Enter a string:
Apple<Enter>
^C
$ cat my.log
User entered: Test
User entered: Apple
$
```

Despite decoupling generation from production, `pipes` still streams everything immediately, so the output stages (i.e. `hPutStrLnD` and `putStrLnD`) will write out the `Strings` immediately after they are generated and won't buffer the `String`s or wait until the program finishes.

Notice that by decoupling the `String` generation from the actual logging action, we gain the ability to inject the `String` consumer dependency at the last moment.

To learn more about how to use `pipes`, I recommend you read [the `pipes` tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html).

Answer (score 5):

If you only have a fixed set of endpoints, this is a possible design:

```
data Logger = Logger [LoggingEndpoint]
data LoggingEndpoint = ConsoleEndpoint ... | FileEndpoint ... | ScribeEndpoint ... | ...
```

Then it should be straightforward to implement this:

```
logWarn :: Logger -> String -> IO ()
logWarn (Logger endpoints) message = forM_ logToEndpoint endpoints
  where
    logToEndpoint :: LoggingEndpoint -> IO ()
    logToEndpoint (ConsoleEndpoint ...) = ...
    logToEndpoint (FileEndpoint ...) = ...
```

If you want expandable set of endpoints, there are some ways to do it, the simplest of which is to define `LoggingEndpoint` as a record of functions, basically a vtable:

```
data LoggingEndpoint = LoggingEndpoint { 
    logMessage :: String -> IO (),
    ... other methods as needed ...
}

consoleEndpoint :: Settings -> LoggingEndpoint
consoleEndpoint (...) = LoggingEndpoint { 
    logMessage = \message -> ...
    ... etc ...
}
```

Then, `logToEndpoint` simply becomes

```
logToEndpoint ep = logMessage ep message
```

Answer (score 2):

In Real World Haskell they describe how to use a Writer monad to do just this, much better than I can explain it: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/programming-with-monads.html#id649416

Also see the chapter on monad transformers: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html